# Azure Devops Conditional Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I am using an NX monorepo. I am currently setting up the CI/CD pipelines for this in Azure DevOps.

The build pipelines are fine I think but looking at the release pipeline I will need some sort of condition check as the build artefacts may or may not be there, given only what has been affected will be built at that time.

For example I have 4 apps in the monorepo and I apply a fix to App2 then only the build artefact for App2 will be available for deployment. For App1,App3 and App4 there will be no artefact

So I was thinking I would have 4 release tasks/templates within the release pipeline- 1 for App1, 1 for App2 etc

In each task/template I would have a condition that checks to see the artefact exists and if so continue release deployment otherwise exit

eg. if $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist/apps/App1 folder exists then do deployment

Is it possible to do something like this in Yaml? (I still mainly use the UI task editor!)

Comment: If you have path filtering applied to your build pipeline then you would produce only artifact where changes really happened. But in this case you need build pipeline per App. Then since only one pipeline was triggered it will only fire one release pipeline. It should handle the case.

Comment: I'm already building only what is affected - I need the deployment to determine what has been built and only deploy that

Comment: Do you have single build pipeline or not? If yes than you don't need any condition and just link your release pipeline with build pipeline. But it would work only when you have it app - build pipeline - release pipeline in 1:1:1 relation.

Comment: i don't think you understand the question. I have 1 build pipeline but that can build between 0 and many artefacts (depending on what has changed) and these artefacts need to be released to between 0 and many app services depending on whether they exist or not

Comment: Yeah I see that. I just told that if ypu split your build pipeline into many that each can generate only 1 artifact you can avoid condition because AzDO detect changes and fire only this pipeline which compile changed files and then you will get single artifact. Having relation 1:1 build pipeline: release pipeline should then solve your issue.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand you that defeats the whole purpose of an NX monorepo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241642/discussion-between-krzysztof-madej-and-72gm).

Comment: I've solved this problem using nx affected + build tags. I documented it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76603663/azure-pipeline-conditional-release-with-nx-monorepo/76603664#76603664

Answer (score 0):

You can use [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) on the deployment step. As example:

1. Add the first step: check folders and update some variable. To update your variable you can use [logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash):

   ```
   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=your_variable]YES"
   ```
2. Use the variable in the condition of the deployment step:

   ```
   and(succeeded(), eq(variables['your_variable'], 'YES'))
   ```

Comment: I think this looks like the right idea... will give it a try